# How do completeness and being closed differ in a subspace?

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I am meant to prove that if $E$ is a finite dimensional subspace of a normed space $X$, then $E$ is a closed subspace.

---

Now I know that if $E$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $X$, then $E$ is complete. I don't know how completeness of $E$ is different to $E$ being closed.

In both cases we want all limit points to be in $E$, and every limit point comes from a convergent sequence, which means there is a Cauchy sequence going to the limit point, which means that completeness guarantees all limit points are in $E$?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one way implication, but that's not all.

First of all the concept of closedness requires the set to be embedded in a (larger) space while completeness can be defined from within the set. For example the set $\mathbb Q$ which is not complete is a property not relying on it being part of $\mathbb R$ (that's why it became apparent before introduction of $\mathbb R$). On the other hand $\mathbb Q$ as an topological space in it's own right the entire set will be closed (since it's the complement of the empty set which in turn is open), but as a subset of $\mathbb R$ it's a non-closed set.

This shows also where the reverse implication doesn't hold. In the topological space $\mathbb Q$ we have that it's not complete, yet the set $\mathbb Q$ is closed.

The proof of the implication is as you write. The crusial part where the reverse doesn't hold is that given a sequence $q_n$ converging to $q$ it will apply that it's a Cauchy-sequence.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me(although the OP didn't appreciate yet)

Comment: @OceansBleed That's because I can't yet upvote.

Comment: Can we find a functional example of a closed subspace which is not a Banach space ?

Comment: @Maman Yes, but only if the superspace is not complete (because a cauchysequence is then convergent and if the subpsace is closed the limit must be in the subspace). For example the subspace $\mathbb Q$ of $\mathbb Q^2$ is closed, but not complete.

Comment: Thank you but I was thinking of spaces like $(\mathcal{C}([0,1],ℝ,  ) ,\vert\vert .\vert\vert_1)$
? What could be a closed set of that ?

Comment: @Maman There's not much very special about them. The examples you give are complete if I get your examples right and therefore closed subspaces of them are complete. If you have a incomplete space there may be both complete and incomplete subspaces (if you allow the trivial cases the whole space it would be incomplete and the 0-only space would be complete).

Comment: I think that for $\Vert.\Vert_1$ the space is not complete. So if we find a closed subspace of it, it will not be complete. Maybe $(\mathcal{C}^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @Maman To take a non-trivial example. Consider the space of piecewise linear continuous functions with supremum norm. This space is incomplete. A closed subset $S_1$ that happens to be complete is the functions which has corner at only integer arguments. A closed subpsace $S_2$ that happens to be incomplete is the functions with support in $[0,1]$. A subspace $S_3$ of $S_1$ consisting of functions that in addition each have compact support is not complete despite $S_1$ being complete, but then $S_3$ isn't closed (in $S_1$) either.

Comment: Indeed nice example !